# server in Java, client in C - cannot get the data

Tags: java, c, sockets, tcp, ip

I am writing code for tcp-ip server client... the problem I am facing is :: My server is in Java and listening to a port, if anything it found simply it prints what it found.

I have a client in Java and a client in C . When I use my Java client and send String "hello server" - the server finds that and prints that BUT when the C client sends it using the "send" of winsock.h, the Java server gives error on the line :: (I have used Buffereader and readline to get the data from tcp-ip port in Java server)

```
        commandFromPortal = inFromClient.readLine();
```

and the errors are ::

```
           Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at org.snmp4j.NOCAlarmManager.Clientnew.run
```

**What should I do ??? Any suggestion ??**

Comment: Providing more information about the C client may help in this situation, at least opening the socket and sending the data.

Comment: Posting relevant code might help.  Is it a buffering issue? Make sure you end the string you send with a newline, and try flushing after.

Comment: Post the socket reading code from your server.

Comment: Java stores strings in UTF, not ascii. Try either reading raw bytes on the server, or send UTF string from C client.

Comment: @Kevin :: I add a newline at end of the char array that was sent from the C client.... and it worked ... thanks... BUT is it possible by not adding a \n at end of the string ? should I change my bufferreader of java server ???

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the socket is buffering when you write to it and the queued data is not being flushed (sent) before you close the socket (you are closing it properly, right?).  The fact that it works when you add a newline (`\n`) seems to confirm this.  So you have to flush the buffer on the socket before you close it.  I don't work with winsocks, but from [this website](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/networking-device-communication/61375-flush-socket.html) I gather you should call `shutdown(sock,SD_SEND)` (if that doesn't work, check the winsock documentation for how to flush the socket buffer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Middleware to introduce transparency.

Middleware frameworks are designed to mask heterogeneity of networks and hardware.  Most middleware frameworks also mask heterogeneity of operating systems or programming languages, or both.
A few such as **CORBA** could be used.

Comment: No kidding ... while at it, also add a database - can't live without one (or two or three), and a management system, and some web framework for reporting. That way you'll get even more transparency.